# Replace/clean unknown characters <?> from an XML File in Android

Tags: android, xml, character-encoding, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML generated by a program. This program seems to have some issues with Spanish special chars like ñ or á, é, í, ó, ú etc. So the XML replace those chars with �.

When I parse the XML in Android and I get any string containing a � it shows an error "not well-formed (invalid token)".

How can ignore those � so I don't get an error in my Android app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the XML parse gets the characters right. The symbol “�” indicates character-level data error, most commonly caused by reading an ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 encoded file as if it were UTF-8 encoded,

Comment: The XML I am parsing starts with:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the ñ or á, é, í, ó, ú issues of character, use this encoding

```
output = new String(long_desc.getBytes("8859_1"), "utf-8");
```

It will shows the chareacter in proper format. And for  �  its html error. to remove it use `Html.fromHtml(your_variable which hold above data);`